# iOS Enterprise in house app distribution error

Tags: ios, certificate, profile

We are using xcode 6.2 beta 4 and distributing ipa with testflight without any issue.

But when distribute the ipa to an OTA link for enterprise in-house distribution, the app can't be installed. The error message captured in the console log is "attempt to install an invalid profile", "Failed to verify code signature of ...", "Signer did not match any installed provisioning profile".

The Distribution Provisioning Profiles being used is showing green in the Apple developer portal. And it's available in the Xcode. The certificate type is iOS Distribution and will expire on Jan 06, 2016. The profile has both bundle ID and cert in place.

The ipa was generated via the build, not the archive (as archive doesn't allow me to export as enterprise ipa, only ad hoc).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong type of provisionning profile. It needs to appears as `iOS UniversalDistribution` in the provisionning profile list . When creating your provisionning profile, choose `Distribution > In House`

Comment: Emilie - Thanks for the quick comment. But I don't see the option. In my developer portal, I have a Provisioning Profile Section. Clicking on Distribution, I only see three options. 1. Development. 2 Distribution: App Store or Ad Hoc. Does that mean I don't have the correct account to do it?

Comment: If you have only and Apple Developper Program account, you won't be able to make a universal build that can be installed on any device : you are limited to 100 devices. What you need, if you want to be able to distribute to an unlimited amount of In-House devices is an Apple Enterprise Program Account

Comment: In my Developer Account Summary, it shows Account Type: Company/Organization. Doesn't it mean the "Enterprise Program Account"?

Comment: No, what you have is an normal Apple Developper Program, one with which you cas submit apps for the App Store, but not for In-House. In an Enterprise Account, account type is `In-House`. You need to register to [Apple Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)